# My Dijkstra algorithm's not choosing the shortes path

Tags: c++, algorithm, queue, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

i tried to code Dijkstra algorithm with two custom structs of vertexes and their edges for my custom graph, the algorithm compiles but it makes wrong choice choosing the best distance. the code is as following.

```
class Graph {
struct Edge;
struct Vertex {
    std::string _data;  //name of vertex    
    std::list<Edge*> _ins;
    std::list<Edge*> _outs;
    bool visited;
    int BestDist;//best distance from source to sink

};
struct Edge {
    int _weight;
    Vertex *_from;
    Vertex *_to;
    bool travelled; //if the edge has been travalled
};
//Graph of String as key to Values as vertexes
std::unordered_map<std::string, Vertex *> _mainData; 

//Dijkstra Algo
int BestDistance(std::string source, std::string sink) {

    //to save vertexes names
    std::queue<std::string> q;

    //for each vertex set dist and path to infinity
    for (auto startItr : _mainData)
    {
        startItr.second->BestDist = Max;
        startItr.second->visited = false;
        for (auto kachal : startItr.second->_outs)
        {
            kachal->travelled = false;
        }
    }

    //set source distacne to 0 sicen it is visiting itself
    _mainData[source]->BestDist = 0;
    q.push(source);

    //while there is unknown distance vertex and we havent reach sink yet
    while (!q.empty() )
    {
        //smallest unknow distance vertex
        std::string currentVer = q.front(); q.pop();
        //set that vertex to visited
        _mainData[currentVer]->visited = true;

        //for each vertex adj to current vertex
        for (auto adjVer : _mainData[currentVer]->_outs) {
            //if that vertex is not visted
            if (!adjVer->travelled) {
                int cvw = adjVer->_weight; //cost of edge from cuurent vertex to adj vertex

                //if current vert.distance +cvw < adj vertex distance
                if (_mainData[currentVer]->BestDist + cvw < _mainData[adjVer->_to->_data]->BestDist) {
                    //update adj vertex
                    q.push(adjVer->_to->_data);
                    //deacrease adj vertex distacne  to current distacne + cvw
                    _mainData[adjVer->_to->_data]->BestDist = _mainData[currentVer]->BestDist + cvw;
                    //marked the travlled edge true
                    adjVer->travelled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return _mainData[sink]->BestDist;
}
```

and here is my main:

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include "Graph.h"
 #include <iostream>

int main()
 {
 Graph myGraph;
 myGraph.Add("A");
 myGraph.Add("B");
 myGraph.Add("C");
 myGraph.Add("D");
 myGraph.Add("E");
 myGraph.Add("F");
 myGraph.Add("G");

 myGraph.Connect("A", "B",20);
 myGraph.Connect("A", "C",30);
 myGraph.Connect("B", "D",200);
 myGraph.Connect("C", "F",100);
 myGraph.Connect("C", "G",200);
 myGraph.Connect("D", "E",50);
 myGraph.Connect("E", "F",1);
 myGraph.Connect("F", "G",30);
 std::cout << "best distacne example : " << myGraph.BestDistance("A", "G");
```

so when i run the code, the best distance from A to G shoudl be returned as 160 (A->C->F->G)  but the code returns 280 which is (A->C->G). I can provide my Add and Connect functions but i'm sure they are working correctly.

Comment: Dijkstra's algorithm works very well, and makes the right choice, always.  It is ***your faulty implementation*** of the algorithm that does not work.

Comment: Create a test case with two nodes and see if it returns the correct value.  Then 3...

Comment: @MikeNakis yes you are true, sorry for my bad English. my implementation of Dijkstra sucks at the moment.

Comment: @stark : most test cases works fine unless a Vertex has two or more inputs. in that case which ever way that reach that vertex is set to best distance i guess no matter what the weight of each edge is

Comment: Godd! You have found something.  Now use a debugger or add print statements to find out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after analyzing above algorithm i realized my mistake was to mark each edge as being traveled or not and make decisions based on that. what i should have done was to mark each Vertex for being visited or not . the rest is ok. so this is the correct version of my implementation of Dijkstra Algorithm finding the shortest path in a positively weighted graph. hope it helps

```
//Dijkstra Algo
int BestDistance(std::string source, std::string sink) {

    //to save vertexes names
    std::queue<std::string> q;

    //for each vertex set dist and path to infinity
    for (auto startItr : _mainData)
    {
        startItr.second->BestDist = Max;
        startItr.second->visited = false;
    }

    //set source distacne to 0 sicen it is visiting itself
    _mainData[source]->BestDist = 0;

    q.push(source);

    //while there is unknown distance vertex and we havent reach sink yet
    while (!q.empty() )
    {
        //smallest unknow distance vertex
        std::string currentVer = q.front(); q.pop();

        //set that vertex to visited
        _mainData[currentVer]->visited = true;

        //for each vertex adj to current vertex
        for (auto adjVer : _mainData[currentVer]->_outs) {
            //if that vertex is not visted
            if (!adjVer->_to->visited) {
                int cvw = adjVer->_weight; //cost of edge from cuurent 
                                           //vertex to adj vertex

                //if current vert.distance +cvw < adj vertex distance
                if (_mainData[currentVer]->BestDist + cvw < 
                   _mainData[adjVer->_to->_data]->BestDist) {

                    q.push(adjVer->_to->_data);

                    //deacrease adj vertex distacne  to current distacne + cvw
                    _mainData[adjVer->_to->_data]->BestDist = _mainData[currentVer]->BestDist + cvw;
                    //setting the path of adj vertext to his previous one
                    _mainData[adjVer->_to->_data]->path = _mainData[currentVer]; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return _mainData[sink]->BestDist;
}
```

Comment: surely there are many other better and optimized solutions out there. I'm a novice in programming so i apologize if the code is flawed. i appreciate any suggestions and comments on how to make it better or more efficient